# Pseudorandomity in concurrent programs

Tags: java, random, concurrency

I'm writing a program that generates a lot of random numbers. I used to set a fixed seed at the beginning to keep results replicable. The problem that I am facing now is that in a naive implementation I lose the pseudorandomity due to concurrency.

My question is this: Is it possible to preserve pseudorandomity without having inter-thread communication and if so, how?

The following code should illustrate my problem. Each run, the program returns a different triple of sums. Obviously, the order of access will also differ most of the time.

```
public class PseudorandomConcurrency {

    private static Random rng;
    private static int numDraws = 2;
    private static int numThread = 3;
    private static int numRuns = 3;
    private static int order;

    public static class Generator implements Runnable{

        private static synchronized void incOrder(){
            order++;
        }

        private static synchronized int getOrder(){
            return order;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int sum = 0;
            ArrayList<Integer> order = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int j = 0; j < numDraws; j++) {
                incOrder();
                order.add(getOrder());
                sum += rng.nextInt(10);
            }
            System.out.println(sum+" order: "+order.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < numRuns; i++) {
            order=0;
            System.out.println("#####");
            rng = new Random(1);
            ArrayList<Thread> threads= new ArrayList<Thread>();
            for (int j = 0; j < numThread; j++) {
                threads.add(new Thread(new Generator()));
            }

            for (Thread thread : threads) {
                thread.start();
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps use the one random number generator (with fixed seed) to generate seeds for individual RNGs in the threads

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is this: Is it possible to preserve pseudorandomity without having inter-thread communication and if so, how?

Yes it is. Make each thread use a separate random number generator (with a different but deterministic seed).

Comment: Thanks. For my example problem I think this should do it. However, would this still work when I have threads generating threads (which will be the case in my final program)?

Comment: Yes, just put the seed as an argument to the constructor and pass the next random number from the "ParentThread".